# Chinese garbled in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I use GeoServer to publish shapefiles with GeoMesa-Accumulo, but when I click on the map, I see some garbled in map.

How can I have it display Chinese characters?

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323836/arabic-labels-do-not-display-correctly-in-geoserver/56406278#56406278

Answer (score 1):

Just to include content from the link Ian shared. The main issue appears to be resolved with

> So experimenting with your shapefile and SLD and googling "windows arabic character set" led me to setting the Shapefile datastore DBF character set to "Windows-1256" which seems to work.
>
> using a "better" font than Arial (Trocchi) fills out the Chinese as well as the Arabic characters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,but it doesn't seem to work. If I just publish shapefiles with geoserver,I can choose the DBF character in datastore,it  OK. But I used the GeoMesa-Accumulo,I can't choose the DBF character from geoserver.